# what is the difference between refresh rate and frame rate in browser when it comes to requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, animation, browser, rendering, frontend

As i know, for common displays, the refresh rate is 60/s, but what is frame rate when it comes to rendering process in browser? I have checked many refs that tell me if you want get a better animation performance, you need to keep frame rate sync with refresh rate and it will be good using requestAnimationFrame. what does this really mean? Who produces a frame in a animation made by javascript execution? is it produced by javascript itself? Then what about a css transition? Can somebody explain this for me in detail? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A browser determines the rate at which it refreshes the window. It's possible to refresh at a rate greater than this in JavaScript (e.g. by doing `setInterval(redraw, 10)` which redraws every 10ms (100 fps)), but going higher than the browser's refresh rate is frivolous; the browser will not rerender that quickly and thus you are wasting computing time building frames that will not be shown.

`requestAnimationFrame` helps with this by calling your function -- presumably a redraw function -- before every browser repaint. This ensures that you only perform redraws when they will actually be shown. This makes for better performance; it guarantees that redraw calculations will not be performed needlessly. It is especially beneficial if those redraw calculations are computationally expensive.

Helpful documentation: [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: "requestAnimationFrame helps with this by calling your function -- presumably a redraw function -- before every browser repaint" Does what you are saying "before every browser repaint" here mean "before every browser refresh the display"?Cause as i know, in browser main thread, the execution line is js execution->style computing->relayout-> repaint. But i guess the operation of "refreshing  the display" does not lie in the main thread, but in another thread.

Comment: Correct. Browsers' repaint operations happen separately from JS execution threads. Long story short: use `requestAnimationFrame`.